# Invalid Array Assignment

Tags: c

i don't know where is the problem i'm assigning the address to other 2 dimensional array. Please help me to fix this problem

```
int main()
{
    int a[3][2];
    int b[2]={0,1};
    a[2]=b;
    return 0;
}
```

`prog.cpp:8:9: error: invalid array assignment`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't copy an array using `=`. Neither can you assign an array's address; `x = y;` doesn't work either when `x` and `y` have types `char[1]` for example. To copy the contents of `b` to `a[2]`, use [`memcpy`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/memcpy.3.html):

```
memcpy(a[2], b, sizeof(a[2]));
```

Answer (score 2):

you should iterate each element of `b[2]` one by one and store into it `a[2]`
try this:

```
int main()
{
    int a[3][2];
    int b[2]={0,1};
    for(int i=0;i<2;i++){
     b[i]=a[2];
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Because the standard says so. Arrays cannot be assigned, only initialized.
so 
C:

```
int i;
for(i = 0; i < 2; i++)
{
  a[2][i] = b[i];
}
...
```

C++: you can use strcpy!

Comment: oh, you can use memcpy

Answer (score 0):

This assignment is not possible.Array allow specific location  assignment.
you can try like this:

```
int main()
{
    int a[3][2];
    int b[2]={0,1};
    a[0][0]=b[0];
    a[0][1]=b[1];
    return 0;
}
```