# How to insert a string in a node (as entered by the user)? (Binary Search Tree)

Tags: c, arrays, string, binary-search-tree, insertion

I am trying to create a Binary search tree using C. What I am required to do is insert an id (only numbers) in a node and associate the same node with a name (a string).  Using this id, I get to display the tree using InOrder Searching.

The problem is, I got (thanks, internet) the numbers to insert, do the InOrder search.

What I fail to do is associate the string with the node, i.e, I am unable to store the names. I did find an answer to doing the same in a linked list, but I do not seem to comprehend the code. Please, help me.

What I found was memset() {I have no clue what that is} and somehow I am supposed to use stringcpy {I know this, but don't know how to apply it}

My structure code:

```c
struct node
{
    int employeeid;
    struct node *left;
    struct node *right;
    char employeename[100];
}*temp=NULL,*link=NULL;
```

Inside my function I tried to insert the name, but got an error:

```c
    printf("Enter the employee name: ");
    gets(name);
    temp = (struct node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    temp->employeeid = data;
    temp->employeename = name;
    temp->left = temp->right = NULL;
```

The line of code with the error:
`temp->employeename = name;`

The error:

`error: assignment to expression with array type`

What I expected was obviously the code to run. Please help.

Comment: Arrays are  not assignable in C as you're doing. [See this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33118140/invalid-array-assignment) for more information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use the `=` operator with an array. You need to use a function such as `strcpy`, `strncpy` or `memcpy`. And you need to ensure that `employeename` is null-terminated.

I would strongly recommend that you use `fgets` instead of `gets`. In fact you should probably never use `gets`. `fgets` will take care of the null-termination (assuming that the buffer `name` is not larger than `employeename`) and will not overrun your buffer.

Don't forget to check `malloc` return value. You want to handle error properly rather than crashing when it happens.

Using `fgets`, with some error handling and `BUFF_SIZE = 100`:

```
temp = (struct node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
if (temp == NULL)
{
    printf("Malloc has failed\n");
    return (-1);
}
printf("Enter the employee name: ");
fgets(name, BUFF_SIZE, stdin);
temp->employeeid = data;
strcpy(temp->employeename, name);
temp->left = temp->right = NULL;
```

EDIT:

`stdin` is the standard input. To put it simply, this is what normally hold the text that you are writing with your keyboard in your terminal. And this is what `scanf` and `gets` are using without asking you. Keep in mind that I cut corners with this explanation.

`BUFF_SIZE` is a convenient way to represent a constant value. The best way to set it up is to use a define, like this, at the top of your program:

```
# define BUFF_SIZE 100

int all_your_function()
{
...
```

This is very useful when you want to:

- give a meaningful name to a specific number (so your program is easier to read)
- modify this number in your whole program (only one place to overwrite)

Comment: Thank you for the informative code and explanation. It worked perfectly. However, I still didn't get why we used `BUFF_SIZE` and `standin`. What purposes do they serve?

Comment: `BUFF_SIZE` is a convenient way to avoid typing `100` all the time, and it's easier to modify. `stdin` is the standard input: when you type with your keyboard on your terminal with function such as `scanf`, or `gets`, this is where the character ends up. I'll edit my answer for clarification.